# React Navigation Mounts with Previous Navigation Params, then New Params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

We are seeing a strange behavior in our React Native + React Navigation application, so we've created a simple example to demonstrate.

We have 2 screens: A and B.

On Screen A, there are two buttons that each navigate to Screen B. The first button passes parameter id:1, the second passes id:2.

On Screen B we are console logging the inbound parameter in both the render() method and componentDidMount() method.

If I click the button with id:1 on Screen A, the parameter output on Screen B is corrected logged as id:1 in both render() and componentDidMount(). However if I then navigate back and very quickly click the button with id:2, the logged output is first shown as id:1, then as id:2. In the following order:

**First click:**

render: 1

componentDidMount: 1

(then back, then *quickly*:)

**Second click**

render: 1

render: 2

componentDidMount: 1

componentDidMount: 2

It would seem that the ghost of the previously mounted component is still haunting our application. Moreover, it feels like a race condition because you have to click quickly to summon the ghost, a slow click will not cause this behavior.

Here is the whole of the application:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
class ScreenA extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (      
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginVertical: 12, padding: 32, borderWidth: 1 }} 
          onPress={() => { navigation.navigate( 'ScreenB', { id: 1 })}}>
          <View style={{ }}><Text>Button 1</Text></View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginVertical: 12, padding: 32, borderWidth: 1 }} 
          onPress={() => { navigation.navigate( 'ScreenB', { id: 2 })}}>
          <View style={{ }}><Text>Button 2</Text></View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
class ScreenB extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('%c componentDidMount: '+this.props.navigation.state.params.id, 'padding: 2px; background: blue; color: #fff')
  }
  render() {
    console.log('%c render: '+this.props.navigation.state.params.id, 'padding: 2px; background: green; color: #fff')
    return (   
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ padding: 16 }} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
          <View style={{ }}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        </TouchableOpacity>        
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const Router = StackNavigator({
  ScreenA: { screen: ScreenA },
  ScreenB: { screen: ScreenB }
})
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router />
    )
  }
}
```

Also here is a Snack:

https://snack.expo.io/@makerepeat/navigation-bugs

... and the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rn2-test2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is how `navigation.navigate` works. If you use it without passing the key for the next screen, `react-navigation` won't match it with the screen that is already mounted hence mounting another one.

What you can observe here is exactly the case when the component was not yet unmounted but navigate doesn't know that and renders another instance of the same component.

You can prevent this by passing the key param into `navigate` function as follows:

```
navigation.navigate({routeName: 'ScreenB', key: 'ScreenB', params: { id: 1}})

navigation.navigate({routeName: 'ScreenB', key: 'ScreenB', params: { id: 2}})
```

Now `StackNavigator` can check if screen with the same key already exists and prevent it from mounting.

Comment: We completely mis-understood the purpose of the key. Thank you so much, you are awesome.